# pstoedit does not create svg

Tags: svg, latex, inkscape

In reality, I detected the original problem when using `Inkscape 0.91` - it has an option to render `Latex` images on an `SVG` surface. Digging a little, it seems that the problem is due to `pstoedit` failing, which, when called separately reports:

```
$ pstoedit -f svg test.ps test.svg
pstoedit: version 3.70 / DLL interface 108 (built: Sep 25 2017 - release build - g++ 4.9.3 - 64-bit) : Copyright (C) 1993 - 2014 Wolfgang Glunz
Unsupported output format svg
```

Digging still deeper, it seems that `pstoedit` uses plotutils to do the work, but, from tests, `plotutils` seems to do what it is supposed to do:

```
echo 0 0 1 1 2 0 | spline | graph > test.meta
```

succesfully creates a `test.meta` file with a spline in it, while

```
plot -T svg test.meta > test.svg
```

converts that metafile correctly to `test.svg`

Versions installed are:

- plotutls 2.6   (seems Ok, creates svg)
- pstoedit 3.7   (works, except for svg)
- Inkscape 0.91  (Latex appears in the  `extensions | render` menu
                but doesn't work - because pstoedit doesn't generate
                the required svg)

I've also reviewed the `./configure` options to check if something was missing - no luck.

Distribution is `Slackware64-current`. As `Slackware` always installs the header files, no header files (-dev, -devel...) are missing here (I've checked too. And recompiled `pstoedit` after installing `plotutils`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging even deeper, I found the reason for the problem. `Slackware64` installs libraries to `/usr/lib64`, so the the `pstoedit` plugins were installed in `/usr/lib64/pstoedit`. But it seems that `pstoedit` does NOT look in that directory when trying to load the plugins at runtime - it looks for `/usr/lib/pstoedit` instead.

It then reports supporting several formats except `svg` - giving the impression it did find some plugins. In a `Debian` bug report I found that the reporter checked the plugin search using the `-verbose` command line option, which doesn't exit (it's just `-v`)

Anyway, I solved the issue (for the moment) by making a symlink from `/usr/lib/pstoedit` to `/usr/lib64/pstoedit`. I'll send a report to the program author too.